# share global variable: interaction between main, lib.a and dll

Tags: c, dll, hyperlink, static-libraries

i kept the essential.

caller.exe loads the dll, then calls the function dll_init declared inside the dll.

this last function calls the function "get_ptr" declared in the common library which should return a pointer to the global variable.

the issue is:

- whenever caller.exe calls "get_ptr" it returns a valid pointer same as the one which was previously allocated on caller.exe start fine.
- whenever the dll thru it function "dll_init" (after bein called by
  caller.exe) calls "get_ptr" (knowing that the dll is linked to the
  static lib) it return NULL pointer.

what i am missing ?

### libcommon.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
/***************header****************/
int *get_ptr(void);
int set_ptr(void);
/**********************************/

int *global=NULL;
//extern __declspec(dllimport) int *global; doesnt work

int set_ptr() {
    global = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("global allocated to %p\n",global);
    *global=485; //random value
    return 0;
}

int *get_ptr() {
    return global;
}
```

here is compiling commands (makefile simplified):

```
gcc.exe -c libcommon.c -o libcommon.o -m32
ar r libcommon.a libcommon.o
ranlib libcommon.a
```

### module.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLLIMPORT int dll_init(void) {
    int *ptr=(int *) get_ptr();

    puts("dll run");
    printf("from dll global: %p\n",ptr);
    puts("dll end");

    return 0;
}
```

compiling:

```
gcc.exe -c module.c -o module.o -m32 -DBUILDING_DLL=1
gcc.exe -shared module.o -o module.dll -static-libgcc -lws2_32 -m32 -s -L"." -lcommon -Wl,--output-def,libmodule.def,--out-implib,libmodule.a,--add-stdcall-alias
```

### caller.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef void(voidfunc)(void);
voidfunc *fct_ptr;

int test(int a) {
printf("%d",a++);
}

int main() {
    set_ptr();
    printf("::%p\n",get_ptr());

    /* Load the dll then call dll_init */
    HMODULE dllptr = LoadLibrary("module.dll");
    if (dllptr != NULL) {
        fct_ptr = (voidfunc *) GetProcAddress(dllptr, "dll_init");
        puts("loaded");
        if (fct_ptr != NULL)
           fct_ptr();
        FreeLibrary(dllptr);
    }
}
```

compiling:

```
gcc.exe caller.c -o caller.exe -m32 -static-libgcc -lws2_32 -L. -lcommon -m32
```

Comment: I believe you have 2 different places in memory named ``global``. One is in caller since you compiled it statically with lcommon. Data is set there via ``set_ptr``. Second is in ``module`` space (for the same reasons), but you never called ``set_ptr()`` there. Check memory address of ``global`` inside ``dll_init`` and in ``main``. If they are not the same, you then need to call ``set_ptr`` in your `dll_init``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe you have 2 different places in memory named global. One is
>   in caller since you compiled it statically with lcommon. Data is set
>   there via set_ptr. Second is in module space (for the same reasons),
>   but you never called set_ptr() there. Check memory address of global
>   inside dll_init and in main. If they are not the same, you then need
>   to call set_ptr in your `dll_init``

he's right, i think the common static library linked with both exe and dll was a wrong idea.
the solution is here: [.dll Plugin that uses functions defined in the main executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454968/dll-plugin-that-uses-functions-defined-in-the-main-executable)

Any other suggestions are welcome