# Why does LoadLibrary fail with error code 193?

Tags: c, windows, dll, dynamic-linking

I have built a C `.exe` application, and a DLL to be loaded dynamically by the app using `LoadLibrary`.

The DLL uses functions defined in the main executable.

On my first attempt to build the DLL, the linker failed with `undefined reference` errors.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454968/dll-plugin-that-uses-functions-defined-in-the-main-executable) about the same problem, it has been suggested in one of the answers to create an import library, for the main executable. When building the DLL we can then link it against the executable's import library.

I have implemented this solution. I used

```
dlltool --export-all-symbols mainprogram.exe -l libmainprogram.a -D mainprogram.exe
```

to create an import library for the main executable. (By the way, it ended up weighing almost half of the size of the executable. Does that make sense?)

I then linked the DLL to the import library like so:

```
gcc mydll.c -shared -Wl,--subsystem,windows -D MYDLL_EXPORTS -o mydll.dll -I<main_program_headers> -L<main_program_dir> -lmainprogram
```

The DLL is now successfully created.

However, when the main app calls `LoadLibrary` on the DLL it gets an error code 193.

Internet search suggests that 193 means the DLL is of incompatible bitness to the main executable. However, I have used [the answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows) to determine that both the main program and the DLL are 64-bit.

This technique doesn't work for the import library file itself. I haven't been able to determine its bitness.

What can be causing the 193 error code? If it may be related to the bitness of the import library how can I determine it? If not, what are the other options? Any thoughts?

Comment: If somebody stumbles upon this in the future: I gave up on trying to make functions in the main executable available directly to the DLL plugin. It might be possible (frustrating thing is that the CPython extension system seems to be able to do it), but  the answer on this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454968/dll-plugin-that-uses-functions-defined-in-the-main-executable) suggests it's rare and not robust. I resort to simply passing the loaded DLL a struct with function pointers after loading it. Not as elegant but simpler to do.

Comment: Did you use `__declspec(dllexport)` for the functions in the main executable that you use in the DLL?